# Error when trying to get the JSON from this website

Tags: python, json, url

I need to get the json file from a website but I am not sure how to do it. Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://doi.org/10.5281/zenodo.1212660"
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.json())
```

But I am getting this error: `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 2 column 1 (char 1)`

What should I do? Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure it's returning JSON?

Comment: Usually you get JSON from an API, not from a regular website.

Comment: @Barmar thank you for your reply. I am not sure actually (it's the first time I am doing this honestly). I need to go to that page and download something from there (I need to do this for multiple pages, hence why I want to automate the process). How can I do that (use the API instead of the website)?